# dropbox linkFromController detect cancel

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I upgraded DropBox framework in my app and now I have to use linkFromController.

There is a way to detect if user tap on cancel button or if the DropBox auth popup is visible or not?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Following delegate to filter the loading url. Find url that load in cancel button and use it to complete your task.

```
  - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

        NSString *url = [[request URL] absoluteString];

          if([url isEqualToString:@"Cancel Url"]){

            //Do what you want
            return NO;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. You pointed me in the right direction. I checked the url in the (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url and used notification center.